# mongo shell unusable, but access from my program is ok, after uninstalling/new install on OSX

Tags: mongodb

all!

After uninstalling current stable (with brew), and installing the 2.4 rc2 (not brew, since brew --devel does not have it, but mainly as described here: http://shiftcommathree.com/articles/how-to-install-mongodb-on-os-x), even a couple of times, and perhaps being too eager to delete everything mongodb-related before the next install, I have ended up with this situation:

The Node-program I have that uses the database and works ok (find, insert and so on). But the problem is that the mongo shell does not work properly, I cannot insert or find documents. For example (now I have 2.4 rc2, but the situation was the same with the current stable):

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.0-rc2
connecting to: test
> show dbs
local   0.078125GB
> use mydb
switched to db mydb
> db.mydb.mycollection.insert = ({title: "O-oh, strange problem"})
{ "title" : "O-oh, strange problem" }
> show collections
> show dbs
local   0.078125GB
mydb    (empty)
```

Then I do a insert via my Node-program and do this:

```
> show dbs
local   0.078125GB
mydb    0.203125GB
> use mydb
switched to db mydb
> show collections
mycollection
system.indexes
> db.mydb.mycollection.find()
>
```

Again, in my Node-program, 'find' finds what it should...

Any idea why mongo shell does not work?

Frode

Comment: `insert = ?` What is that syntax? It's a function you should be calling. Why are you doing `use mydb`, then `db.mydb`.xyz? The use switches to that DB. Do you mean to have a collection called `mydb` inside a DB called mydb?

Comment: The "=" was wrong! See comment on Adams answer. I use "use mydb" followed by a insert on a (new) collection in that db, like db.mydb.mycollection.insert(...), as described in http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started/

Comment: Please edit your question and show your node code. It's really confusing trying to understand your "console" style output. You've got a collection called `mydb.mycollection` in a `mydb` database. I'm skeptical that's really what you want.

Comment: That's it! I had misunderstood the tutorial! To insert a new record, I use 'use mydb' and then 'db.mycollection.insert(...)'! I am a total newbie with mongo and must have done it the correct way in the first installment. Thanks a lot! New to Stackoverflow too. If this was an answer, I would have accepted it. Is there some way to make this question "answered"?

Comment: I added an answer with my comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a collection called `mydb.mycollection` in a `mydb` database. It is unlikely that's really what you want. When you `use` a database from the shell, you are then able to reference the database via the `db` object without repeating the database name.

```
use mydb
# db is now implicitly the mydb database
# you no longer refer to it by name
db.mycollection.insert({"name" : "stacks overflowing"})
```

Also note that you were not calling the `insert` function, your code was attempting to set the function to the value of the new object.